# Change Javascript Variable without refresh

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I was wondering how i would go about changing "image.src" in the javascript without refreshing the page(well, without clearing the canvas).

I was thinking about using something like AJAX (i have never used it before) but i'm not sure if that is the right path to go. Could anyone help me out?

Here's my code:

```
<form>
Image URL:<input type="text" size="50" name="i" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['i']?>" />
Background Color:<select name="color" >
<?php if($_REQUEST['color'] == "#000000"){ ?>
  <option value="#000000">Black</option>
  <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
  <?php }else{ ?>
    <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
    <option value="#000000">Black</option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit"/> || Back to the <a href="/cloner/index.php">Home Page</a>
</form>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var imageWidthHalf, imageHeightHalf;
        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        var height = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = height;
            canvas.style.display = 'block';
            document.body.appendChild( canvas );
            var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
            var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
            image.addEventListener('load', function() {
                imageWidthHalf = Math.floor( this.width / 2 );
                imageHeightHalf = Math.floor( this.height / 2 );
                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseEvent, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchEvent, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchEvent, false );
            }, false );
            image.src = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['i']; ?>";
            function onMouseEvent( event ) {
                context.drawImage( image, event.clientX - imageWidthHalf, event.clientY - '50' - imageHeightHalf );
            }
            function onTouchEvent( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
    for ( var i = 0; i < event.touches.length; i++ ) {
                    context.drawImage( image, event.touches[i].pageX - imageWidthHalf, event.touches[i].pageY - imageHeightHalf );
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: if you may allow me to edit your code so that it would look better

Comment: What do you want to change the `img.src` to?  If, in the web page's javascript, you know the URL, it's easy to just set the `img.src = url`.  If you have to fetch what the URL would be from the server, then you would use an ajax call to fetch the URL and then assign `img.src`.

Comment: @ianace if you must, But i alreayd have an answer down below from Joseph Silber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('input[name="i"]').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    image.src = this.value;
}, false);
```